# accelerometer sensor avaiblable in locked screen / screen off mode?

Tags: android, locking, accelerometer, power-management

it seems that there is a bug in froyo with respect to the `onSensorChanged` method when the phone goes to lock screen mode, i.e. there are no values coming from the accelerometer.

I read about this issue in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143102/accelerometer-stops-delivering-samples-when-the-screen-is-off-on-droid-nexus-one?answertab=active#tab-top)

Now, the topic does mention a workaround which involves keeping the screen on, although dimmed, but it seems to me that this would drain the battery.

In my application I don't need the screen to be visible at all (brightness can  be zero), but it should respond to touch.

The application should also respond to shaking and movement.

Would this still drain the battery fast?

EDIT: Is there a difference between screen lock and screen off?