# Permanent SensorEventListener Shake

Tags: java, android

I would like to launch an Activity of my application when a shake event is detected. I would like this to happen outside of my application.

There are many great code snippets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it) and [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Sensor/Shaker/src/com/commonsware/android/shaker/Shaker.java) for example, of how to correctly implement the [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html), but even if I don't unregister the listener, it still gets destroyed.

How do I prevent it from being destroyed and register a 'permanent' listener? I can't find any such examples anywhere... Any links or guidance would be really appreciated.

Finally, how would I go about only listening for such events when the display is on? I understand that this may be a [hardware restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982433/android-accelerometers-not-working-when-screen-is-turned-off) anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can register broadcast receiver for [BOOT_COMPLETED intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) and in [onReceive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) start your background service with a [PARTIAL_WAKELOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) and then register your sensor event listener. Something like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags, int startId) {
    acquireWakeLock();
    registerSensorListener();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterSensorListener();
    releaseWakeLock();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void acquireWakeLock() {
    try {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (pm == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Power manager not found!");
            return;
        }
        if (wakeLock == null) {
            wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getPackageName());
            if (wakeLock == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not create wake lock (null).");
                return;
            }
        }
        if (!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            wakeLock.acquire();
            if (!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not acquire wake lock.");
            }
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Caught unexpected exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private void releaseWakeLock() {
    if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        wakeLock.release();
        wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's given me some further reading to do. Forgive the perhaps stupid question, but isn't acquiring a partial wakelock the opposite of what I want to do!? I don't want the listener preventing the device from sleeping...

Comment: As far as I understand, you do not have a choice. In standby mode your [onSensorChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onSensorChanged(android.hardware.SensorEvent) will never be called.

Comment: That's ok, I don't want it to be when the display turns off. I definitely need to register using BOOT_COMPLETED, but can unregister when display goes off or enters standby - so I don't think I'll need the partial wakelock. But then register again when display/cpu turns back on..?

Comment: Ok, then just handle [Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) and [Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) in your [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)