# Android HTTP POST not working with PARTIAL WAKE LOCK when the phone screen goes dark

Tags: http, android-sensors

I have a code which has an activity with a button which when clicked starts the accelerometer service . 
    Accelerometer service Uses `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` in the `onStart()` as shown :

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 super.onStart(intent, startId);

//Power Manager
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MY WK");

 wl.acquire();
 //Power Manager

 try{
mInitialized = false;
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);  
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
} 
catch(Exception e)
 { 
  Log.e("acc","catch1");
  }
}// end of onStart()
```

and in the onSensorChange(Sensor event) i have the code which logs the data to remote server using HTTP POSt as shown :

```
synchronized public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

          if( event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER )
           {

             //-----------------------------sending it to server---------

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xaxis", xaxis));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yaxis", yaxis));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zaxis", zaxis));

           //------------------

    Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
       public void run() {

    HttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost1 = new HttpPost("http://www.xxxxx.com/filename.php");

       httppost1.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       HttpResponse response1 = httpclient1.execute(httppost1);

    }
    };

    networkThread.start();
    //----------------------------------

  }//and of if

 }//end of onSensorChanged
```

> My problem is : 
>     When the phone screen goes dark ,HTTP stops logging to the server . But when the screen is 
> bright even if the keypad is locked it logs data . 
>       Please help me as i want to make this service run in background and log data to server even when
>  the screen is locked . 
>       So , its working fine till the screen goes dark after which its not logging any data .

```
Does HTTP not work with Partial_WAKE_Lock.

I searched for the answers but could not find any. Hoping to get some help ! 

Thank You
```

Comment: I need urgent solution for this. Please reply as soon as you can . Thanks

Comment: SO is not the place for urgent solutions.

Comment: sorry i din't mean to be rude.. i am very new to this community and to android.. Sorry.

Comment: Fortunately , i have found an answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982433/android-accelerometer-not-working-when-screen-is-turned-off  which says that its not the HTTP post not working but when the screen is off no accelerometer values are generated . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately , i have found an answer in this link [Android accelerometer not working when screen is turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982433/android-accelerometer-not-working-when-screen-is-turned-off)  which says that its not the HTTP post not working but when the screen is off no accelerometer values are generated . Thank you