# Android onSensorChanged Bug: Ways to fix it

Tags: android, kernel, rom, sensormanager, off-screen

So there are plenty of threads and questions regarding the following bug/feature on android devices:

When registering for SensorEvents from SensorManager in Android Development, your application only will be notified until the screen of the device turns off. After that, SensorManager stops delivering events.

Issue Link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708 
Workaround possibility: http://nosemaj.org/android-persistent-sensors 
Detailed investigation: [Android accelerometer not working when screen is turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982433/android-accelerometer-not-working-when-screen-is-turned-off?answertab=votes#tab-top) (see accepted answer)

Unfortunately, proposed workarounds don't work on all devices. It's assumed that this behaviour is related to driver/firmware code, which is hard to access/modify except for custom roms or kernels.

My question: I see the possibility to build a custom kernel or rom which fixes this behaviour. However, I've never messed with kernel in first place. Therefore:

1. is there a known rom/kernel which might have already adressed this issue? I hope there are many people who had the same idea/problem.
2. if not, how high are the chances to get this fixed by my own? Not talking about getting kernel unpacked and rebuilding it but more about finding the exact code spot and modifying it (e.g. decouple screen locking <-> sensorevent listening)?

I'm a developer for several years now and have advanced skills. But maybe some kernel developers or specifically experienced users can give some insight here.

Thank you very much for any input!