# Accelerometer stops working/listening

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm building an Android application which uses accelerometer sensor and sends the value of x-axis, y-axis and z-axis to my server, but the problem is when the screen turns off, accelerometer stops working or in other words stops sending data.

How can I fix this? I'm newbie to Android application development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accelerometer stops delivering samples when the screen is off on Droid/Nexus One even with a WakeLock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143102/accelerometer-stops-delivering-samples-when-the-screen-is-off-on-droid-nexus-one)

Comment: I dont know whether it'a duplicate but still no answer

Comment: It depends on the hardware you are using (see [list of devices](http://www.saltwebsites.com/2012/android-accelerometers-screen-off)).

Answer (score 0):

You should keep CPU on in your device. for do that you have to add this permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and add this code to your code.

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
    "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

For more information about this, please refer to this document.
[Keep the CPU On](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu)

Answer (score -1):

You may try using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/services.html) to run the accelerometer in the backround. So when the screen turns off, the accelerometer would still give you current values.

Comment: This qualifies as a link-only answer, please include the relevant bits from the link so the answer is valuable even when the link dies.