# Android - Acceleration sensor stops when APP goes to sleep

Tags: java, android, sleep, sensors, wakelock

I have the following problem: I want to get acceleration data, even when my phone is in sleep mode, and trigger an event when a threshold is reached.

In the onPause-method I acquire a partial wakelock.
For testing purposes I run a countdown timer in the background to check wether the App is still doing work.
However approx after 1 minute screen off the sensor stops getting data, but the countdown timer still runs.

Do you know why the sensor activity is killed althoug I have acquired a wakelock and the CPU seems to be running?
Do I have to run the sensor in a service?

I am using Android Version 12.
This does not happen with older Android versions (e.g. Android 8).

Comment: Similar topic here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614272/onsensorchanged-stops-being-called-after-3-minutes-of-locked-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614272/onsensorchanged-stops-being-called-after-3-minutes-of-locked-screen)